# QGIS : edit feature is disable after using the merge vector layer tool

Tags: polygon, qgis

I have merged two layers in gpkg format using the merge layer tool. Everything looks correct in the attribute table. Now the problem is that for certain polygons after I have selected them with identify features the view feature from function is disable (see picture below). However, this is not always the case. Polygons where this is the case are marked with a "[2]" at the end (for example western_europe_22_08 - western_europe__merged [2] instead of western_europe_22_08 - western_europe__merged ).
[image]